# How to go about listening to a range of memory addresses in an external application and echo the result with ReadProcessMemory

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory, readprocessmemory

Thanks for reading,

I am messing around with an online game I play to teach myself a little about the ReadProcessMemory API.

I am trying to take the ingame chat room and display it in my application. Using an application I was able to search and find the memory address of the data I need but have encountered a few difficulties.

Here is the code I am using to read from the process's memory:

```
    Dim ProcessToReadFrom As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyGameName")(0)

    'Pass the process to a new instance of our NativeMemoryReader class
    Dim MemoryReader As New NativeMemoryReader(ProcessToReadFrom)
    Dim address_to_read As Integer = Convert.ToInt32("006e3218", 16)
    'Read 400 bytes from some address in the process
    Dim MemoryBytes() As Byte = MemoryReader.ReadMemory(New IntPtr(address_to_read), 400)

    MsgBox("ascii: " & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MemoryBytes).Trim()) 


    MemoryReader.Dispose()
```

Which uses the MemoryReader class shown here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?p=3819578

Using this code, I am able to pull one line of the chat each time, and here lies my question

- The data is spread across many addresses from(006E3218-006E6B46), what is the best way to get ALL the data from this range?

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this!

Yours hopefully,

Steve

Comment: Did you try Dim MemoryBytes() As Byte = MemoryReader.ReadMemory(New IntPtr(address_to_read), 14638) ? It should read the whole area you mention.

Comment: Hello Ivan, Thanks for your reply, I did try this but it just returns the one line as I stated before. I can do it if I manually add ALL the addresses and use the ReadMemory function on all of them ALL the time, however, this is obviously very slow and not good for a chat screen. I've no idea why it isn't reading all the chat and only the first line, I even tried it without .Trim and got the same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, make a bit of reverse engineering on the targeted game will help you to understand how the game actually stores the chat messages in the memory. Maybe they use a buffer with a fixed size to store the message, enabling you to iterate each messages correctly.

In your case, I think the function `ASCII.GetString` only parses the first message because it's terminated by the char `\0`, so no reason to continue.

You must create an algorithm that splits your buffer `MemoryBytes` into several arrays each time the char `\0` is found, then call the function `ASCII.GetString` on each of these arrays.

Also, call ReadProcessMemory for each message is fairly correct in term of speed and can be a good solution for reading message box.